# Hibernate ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxy

Tags: hibernate, osgi

My hibernate setup throws some exceptions but still works. The exceptions are thrown for every entity class defined in mapping xml. My project sets up on OSGI using equinox. The class which could not be found is definitely in classpath.

Hibernate Configuration

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.package.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">url</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
        <property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <!-- C3P0 Connection Pool -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Exception

```
Javassist Enhancement failed: at.mkw.inlocs.common.Mapping
java.lang.RuntimeException: by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/proxy/HibernateProxy
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass3(ProxyFactory.java:344)
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass2(ProxyFactory.java:314)
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass(ProxyFactory.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.getProxyFactory(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.postInstantiate(JavassistProxyFactory.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.<init>(EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:323)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:475)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:295)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1385)
    at at.mkw.inlocs.syncservice.client.LocalDatabase.configureHibernate(LocalDatabase.java:80)
    at at.mkw.inlocs.syncservice.client.LocalDatabase.login(LocalDatabase.java:153)
    at at.mkw.inlocs.swingclient.StartupHandler.createMainframe(StartupHandler.java:123)
    at at.mkw.inlocs.swingclient.Activator.runSwing(Activator.java:142)
    at at.mkw.inlocs.swingclient.Activator.access$6(Activator.java:71)
    at at.mkw.inlocs.swingclient.Activator$7.run(Activator.java:236)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javassist.CannotCompileException: by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/proxy/HibernateProxy
    at javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass(FactoryHelper.java:169)
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass3(ProxyFactory.java:339)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/proxy/HibernateProxy
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass2(FactoryHelper.java:181)
    at javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass(FactoryHelper.java:163)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxy
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:105)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 50 more
```

Comment: This could be relevant : https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-3826

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a common issue with using Hibernate in an OSGi environment. The issue is each bundle has its own class loader and when Hibernate `Class.forname()` is used in hibernate it throws an exception because your mapped class is not on the class path of hibernate class loader. the way around this in equinox is to use what is called buddy class loading. Where in the manfiest of the bundle that contains your hibernate jars you add this:

```
Eclipse-BuddyPolicy: registered
```

Then in the bundle or bundles with mapped classes you add this assuming the name of your hibernate bundle `org.hibernate`

```
Eclipse-RegisterBuddy: org.hibernate
```

Also for it to work you need to add the hibernate bundle as a dependency not through imported packages so make sure this is added in your bundle with mapped classes as well.

```
Require-Bundle: org.hibernate
```

For more information google hibernate buddy

Answer (score 1):

Not all problems are same , even though they all are class not found exception . In my scenario the the persistence bundle which uses Hibernate has the org.hibernate.proxy classes but the bundle which has the hibernate  class does not have the org.hibernate.proxy classes . Importing those classes using Import-Package fixed my issue

METE-INF changes for the issue worked for my scenario

Import-Package: entity,javax.persistence;version="[2.1,3)",javax.xml.bin
 d.annotation,org.hibernate.proxy,javassist.util.proxy

Comment: Adding `Import-Package: org.hibernate.proxy, javassist.util.proxy` solved the problem for me as well. I did not add the `entity, javax.persistence;version="[2.1,3)", javax.xml.bin.annotation` imports, though.